# How to apply rules on update in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, updates, rules

I am new to yii2 and I don't exactly know how to apply same rules of insert into update. Here is my rules for insert and I want all rules to effect on update too.

```
    public $tag;
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'name', 'address', 'state'], 'required'],
        [['user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['tag'], 'safe'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['address'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        [['state'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

Adding 'on' => 'update' doesn't effect in my code. Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: if your rules  are the same for all the action  .. you don't need  a specific declaration for update .. you must configure only if the rules  are different between insert and update

Comment: Which rule are you talking about, the required for example?

Comment: these rules will be applied to the update and insert both until you specify some rules for update only , maybe you are asking something else

Comment: I am new to yii2 and I have read documentation. But my rules are not work in update by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default rules are applied in the creation and update, you only have to create new rules if you want different behaviors between update and create.

To apply the rules just make a `$model->validate()` to check the rules, see this example of the documentation of yii2

```
$model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());

if ($model->validate()) {
    // all inputs are valid
} else {
    // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
    $errors = $model->errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation rules to yii model like this

```
public function rules(){
        return [
        [['boolean_var'],'boolean'],
            [[ 'range_in_string'],'required'],
            [['default_value'],'default','value'=>'DEFAULT VALUE'],
            [['integer_var'],'integer'],
            [['double_var'],'double'],
            [['number_min'],'number','min'=>10],
            [['number_max'],'number','max'=>100],
            [['number_min_max'],'number','min'=>10,'max'=>100],
            [['file_image'],'image'],
            [['file_var'],'file','types'=>['gif','jpg']],
            [['date_var'],'date', 'format'=>'d-m-yy'],

            [['min_string'],'string','min'=>10],
            [['max_string'],'string','max'=>10],
            [['min_max_string'],'string','min'=>5,'max'=>10],
            ['min_max_string2', 'string', 'length' => [4, 10]],

            ['email_var','email'],
            ['url_var','url'],

            [['unique_var'],'unique'],

            [['filter_trim'],'filter','filter'=>'trim'],
            [['filter_trim'],'filter','filter'=>'strtolower'],
            ['filter_custom_function', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
            // your concept
            if($value=='')
            return '';
            return 'Value Changed';}],

            ['range_in_min_max', 'in','range'=>range(5,20)],

            ['range_in','in','range'=>['en','fr','zn'],'strict'=>false], //strict false
            ['range_in_string','in','range'=>['EN','FR','ZN'],'strict'=>true],

            ['custom_validation','custom_function_validation'],

            [['passwordConfirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],     
            [['password','date_var'],'safe'],
        ];
}
```

if you need to trigger only when updating but not creating, you can add a scenario like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username, email and password are all required in "update" scenario
        [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],

        // username and password are required in "login" scenario
        [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'login'],
    ];
}
```

and in your action before calling validate add the scenario

// scenario is set as a property

```
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = 'update';
```